# sql-oHow can I achieve the following in oracle without creating a stored procedure?group by using

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, average

how can ı get this result with using employees table?for salary< average 0
for salary >avg 1

```
employee_id   salary
 a              1
 b              1
 c              0
 d              0
 e              0
 f              1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply calculate the **AVERAGE** of the salary and compare it with the **SALARY** for each employee in the **CASE** expression itself.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT empno,
  2    ename,
  3    CASE
  4      WHEN sal >
  5        (SELECT AVG(sal) FROM emp
  6        )
  7      THEN 1
  8      ELSE 0
  9    END flag
 10  FROM emp;

     EMPNO ENAME            FLAG
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH               0
      7499 ALLEN               0
      7521 WARD                0
      7566 JONES               1
      7654 MARTIN              0
      7698 BLAKE               1
      7782 CLARK               1
      7788 SCOTT               1
      7839 KING                1
      7844 TURNER              0
      7876 ADAMS               0
      7900 JAMES               0
      7902 FORD                1
      7934 MILLER              0

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**Alternate solution** You could use **AVG()** analytic function.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT empno,
  2         ename,
  3         CASE
  4            WHEN sal > avg(sal) OVER(ORDER BY NULL) THEN
  5               1
  6            ELSE
  7               0
  8         END flag
  9  FROM emp;

     EMPNO ENAME            FLAG
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH               0
      7499 ALLEN               0
      7521 WARD                0
      7566 JONES               1
      7654 MARTIN              0
      7698 BLAKE               1
      7782 CLARK               1
      7788 SCOTT               1
      7839 KING                1
      7844 TURNER              0
      7876 ADAMS               0
      7900 JAMES               0
      7902 FORD                1
      7934 MILLER              0

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cross join on the average salary:

```
SELECT     employee_id, 
           CASE WHEN salary > avg_salary THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS salary
FROM       employee
CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(salary)
            FROM   employee)
```

Comment: That is syntactically incorrect. The query used to cross-join has a `GROUP BY` missing, but in any case you can't use GROUP BY. You just need average of salary of all employees.

Comment: @LalitKumarB actually, you don't need a group by, or a join clause for that matter - it's a cross join. But of course, you are right - the query was syntactically incorrect. Edited and fixed.